# How to find shiny-server executable and reference it in shiny-server.sh?

Tags: docker, shiny-server

My docker image build seems to have went well, however, I am having issue with shiny-server executable. Mainly, the shiny-server executable is referenced as following in shiny-server.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure the directory for individual app logs exists
  mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server 
chown shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server

exec shiny-server >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1
```

The above code doesn't work for me (don't know why), so I had to change it to this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure the directory for individual app logs exists
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server

if [ "$APPLICATION_LOGS_TO_STDOUT" = "false" ];
then
    exec shiny-server 2>&1
else
    # start shiny server in detached mode
    exec shiny-server 2>&1 &

    # push the "real" application logs to stdout with xtail
    exec xtail /var/log/shiny-server/
fi
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
$ docker run -p 80:8080 fitfarmz3

*** warning - no files are being watched ***
/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh: line 12: shiny-server: No such file or directory
```

Would appreciate how to resolve this.

Here I include the dockerfile:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev 


# Add shiny user
RUN groupadd  shiny \
&& useradd --gid shiny --shell /bin/bash --create-home shiny



# Download and install ShinyServer
RUN wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    gdebi shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb


# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('Benchmarking', 'plotly', 'DT'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Thanks @Rico ; I have added the dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for some reason, `gdebi` is not installing your `shiny-server`. You can install it this way in your Dockerfile:

RUN wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb

Works for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: My wholehearted thanks to you, Rico! I spent about a month trying to fix this and my image finally shows on 192.168.99.100 ! Thanks for your valuable help.